# Can I wear a lapel pin through airport security?

Tags: airport-security, clothing, tsa

I usually leave my lapel pin in my suit jacket, but if necessary I *can* pack it into my check-in luggage.

For a domestic flight within the U.S., is this something I need to worry about?

Comment: A 'regular' sized lapel pin should not set of the mag.  However, certain 'symbols' might be suspicious if the Screener recognizes or confuses them. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, you can wear it.

> Search Results For:
>
> **lapel pins**
>
> You may transport this item in carry-on or checked baggage.

Source: [MyTSA](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=lapel%20pin)

I do not believe there is any need to pack it into check-in luggage. Just like any other metal items on you, for example a belt buckle, you can take the pin off the jacket and put it in the tray with your other items while you cross the security screening gate.

> **What can I do to prevent an alarm?**
>
> To reduce the likelihood of an alarm that results in pat-down screening, remember to remove all items from your pockets before you go through screening. You should avoid wearing clothes, shoes and jewelry with a high metal content.

**[TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/frequently-asked-questions)**

Specially that the lapel pin is not a prohibited item as declared by TSA. Safety Pins, Bobby Pins and Stick Pins are all allowed both in checked bags and carry on bags. I'm sure a clothing item allowed in carry on bag is also allowed to be worn, even though its best to put it on the belt to avoid triggering the alarm.

**[TSA: What Can I bring?](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/printable)**

Comment: Since I have to put the entire jacket on the belt anyway, I won't even bother taking it out.  Thanks.  (Will accept after I confirm it really works that way!)

Comment: for a minute I read that as "You should avoid wearing clothes" and missed the last part, I was slightly confused as you can imagine​ ;)

Comment: @KeithM so was I, punctuation can be improved in that sentence.